# VGG16 Model Outputs Incorrect dimension - Transfer Learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, image-classification

I am trying to use a pre-trained VGG16 model to classify CIFAR10 on pyTorch. The model was originally trained on ImageNet.

Here is how I imported and modified the model:

```
from torchvision import models

model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True).cuda()
model.classifier[6].out_features = 10
```

and this is the summary of the model

```
print(model)

VGG(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (13): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (18): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (20): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (25): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (27): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(7, 7))
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )
)
```

Now I wanted to train the model on CIFAR10, I created the train loader with batch size = 128.
Below is the training function and I added some printing statements to check if everything is working fine or not. **The problem is the model outputs for each data point a 1000 prediction (as the original - unmodified version).**

```
def train(model, optimizer, train_loader, epoch=5):
    """
    This function updates/trains client model on client data
    """
    model.train()
    for e in range(epoch):
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(data)
            print("shape output: ", output.shape)
            probs = F.softmax(output, dim=1) #get the entropy 
            print("entropy: ", probs)
            _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
            loss = criterion(output, target)
            loss.backward()
            if batch_idx % 100 == 0:    # print every 100 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (e + 1, batch_idx + 1, loss.item()))
            optimizer.step()
    return loss.item()
```

Here is part of the the output which shows the output shape:

```
shape output:  torch.Size([128, 1000])
```

**I don't understand why the model outputs the results in this way. Is there something that I am missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Error

It is pretty simple, all you do here:

```
model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True).cuda()
model.classifier[6].out_features = 10
```

is changing attribute `out_features` of `torch.nn.Linear` layer, **not changing weights which actually carry out the computation!**

In simplest case (see comments for outputted shape):

```
import torch

layer = torch.nn.Linear(20, 10)
layer.out_features # 10
layer.weight.shape # (10, 20)
layer(torch.randn(64, 20)).shape # (64, 10)

layer.out_features = 100

layer.out_features # 100
layer.weight.shape # (10, 20)
layer(torch.randn(64, 20)).shape # (64, 10)
```

Weights are of the same shape, as those are created during `__init__` (and altering `out_features` doesn't change anything).

## Fix

You have to recreate the last layer a-new (it will be randomly initialized), like this:

```
model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
# New layer
model.classifier[6] = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fix and the explanation

Comment: Actually, we can do this at the penultimate FC layer itself (i.e., `model.classifier[3] = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 10)`) since that FC layer (in the original VGG16) is just learning a direct mapping, with non-linearity & dropout of course. Removing it completely won't affect the performance but the model size would be drastically smaller since most of the parameters are in that weight matrix of FC layer.